# ionic cordova javac build android errors

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Stackoverflow Ionic

Hello,

I'm desperatly trying to make ionic work on my Ubuntu 14.04 platform but I always get some errors.

Here are my settings :

```
echo $ANT_HOME
/usr/share/ant
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
echo $ANDROID_HOME
/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/
```

What I do :

```
cd /home/hugo/bin
ionic start myApp blank
cd myApp
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

And problems begin :

```
Creating android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.ionicframework.myapp869163
    Name: myApp
    Android target: android-19
Copying template files...
Project successfully created.
Running command: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/hugo/bin/myApp
add to body class: platform-android
Installing "com.ionic.keyboard" for android
Installing "org.apache.cordova.console" for android
Installing "org.apache.cordova.device" for android
hugo@hugo-N55SL:~/bin/myApp$ ionic build android
Running command: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/hugo/bin/myApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
Buildfile: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 93 source files to /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /home/hugo/ant-build/myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CallbackContext
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaInterface
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaPlugin
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaWebView
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:7: error: package org.apache.cordova.PluginResult does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult.Status;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class IonicKeyboard extends CordovaPlugin{
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol: class CordovaPlugin
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaInterface
    [javac]   location: class IonicKeyboard
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaWebView
    [javac]   location: class IonicKeyboard
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CallbackContext
    [javac]   location: class IonicKeyboard
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionicframework/myapp869163/CordovaApp.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol: class CordovaActivity
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaWebView
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CallbackContext
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaPlugin
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaInterface
    [javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class Device extends CordovaPlugin {
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]   symbol: class CordovaPlugin
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaInterface
    [javac]   location: class Device
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaWebView
    [javac]   location: class Device
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    [javac]                                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CallbackContext
    [javac]   location: class Device
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable super
    [javac]   location: class IonicKeyboard
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         final CordovaWebView appView = webView;
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CordovaWebView
    [javac]   location: class IonicKeyboard
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    [javac]                                                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol: variable cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     View v = cordova.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]   symbol: variable cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable cordova
    [javac]   location: class IonicKeyboard
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     ((InputMethodManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol: variable cordova
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable cordova
    [javac]   location: class IonicKeyboard
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionicframework/myapp869163/CordovaApp.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable super
    [javac]   location: class CordovaApp
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionicframework/myapp869163/CordovaApp.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         super.init();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable super
    [javac]   location: class CordovaApp
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionicframework/myapp869163/CordovaApp.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         loadUrl(launchUrl);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable launchUrl
    [javac]   location: class CordovaApp
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionicframework/myapp869163/CordovaApp.java:27: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable super
    [javac]   location: class Device
    [javac] /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/device/Device.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         String uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    [javac]                                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol: variable cordova
    [javac] 31 errors

BUILD FAILED
/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds

/home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

Reading similar questions on stackoverflow, I Can remove 4 javac compiling errors by editing

```
nano -w /home/hugo/bin/myApp/platforms/android/src/com/ionic/keyboard/IonicKeyboard.java
```

and replacing

```
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
```

by

```
import org.apache.cordova.*;
```

since almost all errors are "cannot find symbol", I guess there is some problems finding cordova packages.
I had to install cordova by :

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

because without sudo I had some EACCES errors, could it comes from that ?

Will I have to manually edit a lot of java files to get rid of all errors or am I missing some config ?

Thanks for your suggestions and help !

Comment: You cant `install -g` without root right.

Answer (score 0):

I use ionic on 14.04 without problems. Sometimes I have similar problemes and have to remove the android plattform via

```
ionic platform remove android
```

and add it again with

```
ionic platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

AppGyver's [Steroids CLI](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) is Linux-compatible and [works with your Ionic project](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/) directly without modifying any files. You can develop with a companion app and use a cloud build service to create stand-alone builds, so no need to compile things locally.

(Disclaimer: I'm a programmer for AppGyver.)